# SQL/mysql - how to display two columns with different value from 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query for approval of documents, where the result display the name and signature with date. How can I get the date for two people approving the document?

```
Select Uname 
case when stepcode=1 then 'approver1' end as 'name of person'
case when stepcode=1 then 'approver1' end as ' date of signed noted'
case when stepcode=2 then 'approver2' end as 'date of signed approved'
from table
```

I tried this, but only one result showed up. Only the name, signature and date of the first approval displayed.

Comment: there is no second approver satisfying the case statement ..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for showing the query code. Can you update this description to also show the table data, and what exact result you expect from the query?

Answer (score 0):

We can only answer this by making some assumptions:

1. the field `stepcode` denotes what stage of the sign off process the record is at
2. value of 1 means `noted` and value 2 means `approved`. A value of 0 means nothing has happened yet
3. approver1 and approver 2 are `NULL` if the action has not yet taken place

If all of the above is true, then there should be no requirement to have a `CASE` statement for the fields... just including the fields within the SELECT statement will bring the values through if they have been completed.

Some validation of data might be required here though if you are not getting the results you are expecting. Running some rough counts for each of the steps and for where they have values in the approver fields would help to make sure your code is working. The following should give you something to work with:

```
 SELECT
  stepcode
  COUNT(TableID) AS NumberAtStep
 FROM table
 GROUP BY stepcode
```

Using these counts, you can then run your statement without the CASE statements and run a manual count to ensure you are seeing the right number of records with the relevant populated columns for each step.

Further information will be required to delve into your problem further however